# Quiero elegir una de las tablas en Sqlite3 para Discord y recibo error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite3

He programado un `bot` el cual usa una base de datos para fichar y así controlar a la gente para que cumpla las horas.

El problema lo tengo cuando quiero elegir una de las tablas de cada persona.

```py
Lista = ['Frankiie', 'Josete']

@bot.command('fichaje')
async def consulta_fichar(ctx, nombre):

   if nombre in Lista:

      cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ?', nombre)

      accion = cursor.fetchall()
```

El problema es que no se hacer que cuando le paso un nombre, coja los datos de la tabla de esa persona, porque por cada persona, tiene una tabla diferente, y no se hacerlo sin repetir código, y pensé que pasándole el nombre desde el comando, funcionaria.

No se si me he explicado bien, ya que soy nuevo, pero el problema lo tengo en el '?', no se si hay otra manera de hacerlo. El error es el siguiente

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
line 85, in wrapped ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs) File "/Users/daniel/Desktop/Personal/Ulfberth_pruebas/main.py", 
line 21, in hola cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ?', str(nombre)) sqlite3.OperationalError: 
near "?": syntax error
```

Gracias de antemano !

Comment: que problema tienes con el `?`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/daniel/Desktop/Personal/Ulfberth_pruebas/main.py", line 21, in hola
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM ?', str(nombre))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Este error me sale, muchas gracias !

Comment: porque hay una tabla por persona? eso no suena para nada correcto. el ? es para reemplazar un parametro. La tabla, no suele ser un parametro, y va a tratar de transformar tu variable a un string (con comillas).... Los errores van siempre en la pregunta, no podemos adivinar que pasa...

Comment: Si cada tabla tiene el nombre de una persona (cosa poco lógica, pero bueno) entonces la consulta debería ser: `sql = f'SELECT * FROM {nombre}'` y en la siguiente línea `cursor.execute(sql)`

Comment: He probado con todo lo que me han puesto, y nada ha resultado.

Igualmente, muchas gracias por las aportaciones, y si alguien es tan amable de decirme como lo podria hacer mejor, estaria encantado

Comment: con la solución de @aeportugal te sale el mismo error??

Comment: Diferente, pero he decidido cambiar toda la estructura ya que creo que lo plantee mal, les deseo lo mejor y muchas gracias Christian por toda la ayuda recibida por tu parte, les deseo lo mejor

Comment: So en algún momento tienes la solución y deseas co.partirla puedes responder a tu propia pregunta. Hasta luego :D